Are Two-Pointers and Recursion the Only Ways to Implement Binary Search?
I know that binary search problems can typically be solved using either the two-pointer (iterative) approach or recursion.
However, I wonder if these are the only two fundamental ways of implementing binary search. My tentative answer is yes, but I can’t seem to formally prove it.
For simplicity, we could focus on 1D or 2D arrays as the search space. However, if this concept can be generalized to higher dimensions or other use cases, that would be even better.
Is there a formal proof that all binary search algorithms must fall into one of these two categories, or could there be a fundamentally different method for performing binary search?
Thanks!
